# Catch mail item preview open event

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I want to change a mailitem's body when the user clicks on it (without getting the changes saved!) before it gets displayed in the preview. I thought the preview control was called the Explorer and I subscribed to the NewExplorer event but it does not fire when I click messages.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Explorers explorers = Application.Explorers;
explorers.NewExplorer += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ExplorersEvents_NewExplorerEventHandler(Open_NewExplorer);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the [SelectionChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/explorer-selectionchange-event-outlook) event on current active [Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/explorer-object-outlook?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) object, by calling [ActiveExplorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/application-activeexplorer-method-outlook) method.

In the [Application.Startup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb147656%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event handler, you'll need to add the handler for the event; your code may looks like ...

```
this.Application.ActiveExplorer().SelectionChange += new Outlook.ExplorerEvents_10_SelectionChangeEventHandler(Explorer_SelectionChange);
```

Inside the handler work with Selection; your code may looks like ...

```
void Explorer_SelectionChange()
{
    if (this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection.Count == 1)
    {
        Outlook.MailItem item = this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1] as Outlook.MailItem;

        if (item != null)
        {
           //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had done exactly that but for some reason the event doesn't fire when I click messages. I've got a breakpoint inside my `CurrentExplorer_SelectionChangedHandler()` but the execution never gets in there. Is there anything that can be preventing this event from firing? Can the active explorer change somehow?

Comment: As you understand, application startup happen once and you need to attach the event over there. You also need to store the object in some variable, otherwise garbage collection on this object will kick before you get the event. To understand it better see full example at [How to: Programmatically Determine the Current Outlook Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268994.aspx)